# Scrape websites with infinite scrolling using selenium and beautifulsoup return repeated elements

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So i have script which uses Selenium and BeautifulSoup to scrape this website: 
'http://m.1688.com/page/offerlist.htmlspm=a26g8.7664812.0.0.R19GYe&memberId=zhtiezhi&sortType=tradenumdown'

But my script keep printing the first 8 elements of the page and disregard the contents appeared when scrolling. This is the script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import unicodecsv as ucsv
import re 
from selenium import webdriver
import time 

with open('list1.csv','wb') as f:
w = ucsv.writer(f, encoding='utf-8-sig')

driver = 
webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\V\Desktop\PY\web_scrape\chromedriver.exe')
base_url = 'http://m.1688.com/page/offerlist.html?
spm=a26g8.7664812.0.0.R19GYe&memberId=zhtiezhi&sortType=tradenumdown'
driver.get(base_url)
pageSource = driver.page_source
lst = []
for n in range(10): 
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    soup = BS(pageSource, 'lxml')
    container = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'container'})
    items = container.findAll('div', {'class' : 'item-inner'})
    for item in items:
        title = item.find('div', {'class' : 'item-price'}).text
        title_ = ''.join(i for i in title if ord(i) < 128  if i != '\n')
        lst.append(title_)
    print lst
    time.sleep(5)
```

The output for each scroll is:

```
[u'0.21', u'0.45', u'1.10', u'3.60', u'2.20', u'6.80', u'1.40', u'3.00']
[u'0.21', u'0.45', u'1.10', u'3.60', u'2.20', u'6.80', u'1.40', u'3.00', u'0.21', u'0.45', u'1.10', u'3.60', u'2.20', u'6.80', u'1.40', u'3.00']
[u'0.21', u'0.45', u'1.10', u'3.60', u'2.20', u'6.80', u'1.40', u'3.00', u'0.21', u'0.45', u'1.10', u'3.60', u'2.20', u'6.80', u'1.40', u'3.00', u'0.21', u'0.45', u'1.10', u'3.60', u'2.20', u'6.80', u'1.40', u'3.00']
```

The first scroll the list has 8 elements, the second scroll the list has 16 elements, the extra 8 elements is repeated from the first scroll. Same thing happens for the rest scrolls.
So the script only return 8 elements even when i use selenium to scroll the site but i want it to print out all elements while scrolling. I would really appreciate it if you guys give me some advices.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this part:

```
items = container.findAll('div', {'class' : 'item-inner'})
    for item in items:
        title = item.find('div', {'class' : 'item-price'}).text
        title_ = ''.join(i for i in title if ord(i) < 128  if i != '\n')
        lst.append(title_)
```

Each time you "scroll" the `items` object becomes one block bigger because when you scroll, the upper content doesn't go away.
You need to get rid of first `n-1` `item`s from `items` to escape duplication.

Comment: That isnt the problem because if you take a look at the list, the last list contains the same 8 elements, like lst3 = 3*lst1, nothing changes.

Comment: But what i dont know is when to stop scrolling, there must be a limit somewhere.

Comment: well, depends on page...if you, for example, start scrolling VK.com feed page, if you have many friends, then feed page will last veeery long=)
Also it depends on how much content do you want. Good thing here is that you can manually limit iterations and get as much content  as you need.
You can actually replace `for` loop on `while` and someday get to the end of page's content=)

Comment: i understand the concept and i dont know if there's some kind error will be raised if the script is longer able to scroll.

Comment: you can anticipate any error using `try - except` clause and set the alternative script behavior in this case.

Comment: Make sense. Thank you very much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148135/discussion-between-dmitriy-fialkovskiy-and-v-anh).

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. let the infinite scroll finish and then get the data;
2. after every content reload, you can compare the data that you already have with the new data and then add it to the list.

Comment: After the infinite scroll the page becomes so heavy that it crashes and fails.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to the problem, by putting the pageSource into the loop and instead of hiding the Chrome in the taskbar, you have to open it or you could use PhantomJS instead of Chrome driver.

```
for n in range(10):
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(2)
pageSource = drive.page_source
soup = BS(pageSource, 'lxml')
container = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'container'})
items = container.findAll('div', {'class' : 'item-inner'})
for item in items:
    title = item.find('div', {'class' : 'item-price'}).text
    title_ = ''.join(i for i in title if ord(i) < 128  if i != '\n')
    lst.append(title_)
print len(lst)
```

Now the output will change, instead of

```
8
8
8
8
```

It will print

```
16
20
28
...
```